# How do I extract all possible methionine residues to the end from a protein sequence?

Tags: ruby, regex, bioinformatics

I am looking to extract all Methionine residues to the end from a sequence.

In the below sequence:

```
MFEIEEHMKDSQVEYIIGLHNIPLLNATISVKCTGFQRTMNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG
```

Original Amino Acid sequence:

```
atgtttgaaatcgaagaacatatgaaggattcacaggtggaatacataattggccttcataatatcccattattgaatgcaactatttcagtgaagtgcacaggatttcaaagaactatgaatatgcaaggttgtgctaataaatttatgcaaagacattatgagaatcccctgacgggg
```

I want to extract from the sequence any M residue to the end, and obtain the following:

```
- MFEIEEHMKDSQVEYIIGLHNIPLLNATISVKCTGFQRTMNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG
- MKDSQVEYIIGLHNIPLLNATISVKCTGFQRTMNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG
- MNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG
- MQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG
- MQRHYENPLTG
```

With the data I am working with there are cases where there are a lot more "M" residues in the sequence.

The script I currently have is below. This script translates the genomic data first and then works with the amino acid sequences. This does the first two extractions but nothing further.

I have tried to repeat the same scan method after the second scan (See the commented part in the script below) but this just gives me an error:

```
private method scan called for #<Array:0x7f80884c84b0> No Method Error
```

I understand I need to make a loop of some kind and have tried, but all in vain. I have also tried matching but I haven't been able to do so - I think that you cannot match overlapping characters a single match method but then again I'm only a beginner...

So here is the script I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "bio" 

def extract_open_reading_frames(input)

  file_output = File.new("./output.aa", "w")
  input.each_entry do |entry|
    i = 1
    entry.naseq.translate(1).scan(/M\w*/i) do |orf1|
      file_output.puts ">#{entry.definition.to_s} 5\'3\' frame 1:#{i}\n#{orf1}"
      i = i + 1 
      orf1.scan(/.(M\w*)/i) do |orf2|
        file_output.puts ">#{entry.definition.to_s} 5\'3\' frame 1:#{i}\n#{orf2}"
        i = i + 1
        #   orf2.scan(/.(M\w*)/i) do |orf3|
        #     file_output.puts ">#{entry.definition.to_s} 5\'3\' frame 1:#{i}\n#{orf3}"
        #     i = i + 1
        #   end
      end
    end 
  end
  file_output.close
end


biofastafile = Bio::FlatFile.new(Bio::FastaFormat, ARGF)

extract_open_reading_frames(biofastafile)
```

The script has to be in Ruby since this is part of a much longer script that is in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "MFEIEEHMKDSQVEYIIGLHNIPLLNATISVKCTGFQRTMNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG"

pos = 0

while pos < str.size
  if md = str.match(/M.*/, pos)
    puts md[0]
    pos = md.offset(0)[0] + 1
  else
    break
  end
end

--output:--
MFEIEEHMKDSQVEYIIGLHNIPLLNATISVKCTGFQRTMNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG
MKDSQVEYIIGLHNIPLLNATISVKCTGFQRTMNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG
MNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG
MQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG
MQRHYENPLTG
```

`md` -- stands for the MatchData object.
`match()` -- returns nil if there is no match, the second argument is the start position of the search.
`md[0]` -- is the whole match (`md[1]` would be the first parenthesized group, etc.).
`md.offset(n)` -- returns an array containing the beginning and ending position in the string of `md[n]`.

Running the program on the string "MMMM" produces the output:

```
MMMM
MMM
MM
M
```

> I have also tried matching but I haven't been able to do so - I think
>   that you cannot match overlapping characters a single match method but
>   then again I'm only a beginner...

Yes, that's true.  `String#scan` will not find overlapping matches.  After `scan` finds a match, the search continues from the end of the match.  Perl has some ways to make regexes back-up, I don't know whether Ruby has those.

Edit:

For Ruby 1.8.7:

```
str = "MFEIEEHMKDSQVEYIIGLHNIPLLNATISVKCTGFQRTMNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG"

pos = 0

while true
  str = str[pos..-1]

  if md = str.match(/M.*/)
    puts md[0]
    pos = md.offset(0)[0] + 1
  else
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: I am getting the error: `match': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError) with this.

Comment: What output do you get for `$ ruby --version`?

Comment: See my add-on for ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Yes, I was running 1.8.. It's working now - will upgrade soon... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
str = "MFEIEEHMKDSQVEYIIGLHNIPLLNATISVKCTGFQRTMNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG"
str.scan(/(?=(M.*))./).flatten
#=> ["MFEIEEHMKDSQVEYIIGLHNIPLLNATISVKCTGFQRTMNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG", MKDSQVEYIIGLHNIPLLNATISVKCTGFQRTMNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG", "MNMQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG", "MQGCANKFMQRHYENPLTG", "MQRHYENPLTG"]
```

This works by capturing loookaheads starting with M and advancing one char at a time.

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know you could capture lookaheads (the parens have to be inside!).  And there used to be a constraint that lookarounds had to be a fixed length.

Comment: @7stud, Yes, that's lookbehind that you're thinking of.

Comment: @user2619878,  Have you read the ruby Array docs for flatten()?

Comment: @7stud I had read it and I just read it again but I still don't understand why it is necessary to have it in this situation.

Comment: @user2619878,   Try running `results = str.scan(/(?=(M.*))./)` and then `p results`.  Then run `results = str.scan(/(?=(M.*))./).flatten` and `p results`.